# Keep copy of all data when the data updates periodically

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

My sheet gets updated automatically every five minutes. How can I save the previous data, i.e., data just before each update, so that I can keep all data. I also want to make a line graph which automatically redraws after each update, every 5 minutes. Note: if you need my google sheet I will share it with you.

Answer (score 1):

You will need an Apps Script function that periodically stores archival copies of the data. The function should run on a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers).

To exclude data that has already been archived, insert a helper sheet, and use the `=filter(isna(match()))` pattern to only get rows that are present in the data but not in the archive. Then point your archival function to the helper sheet.

See these scripts for sample code:

- [appendRowsToArchiveSheet](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/41717054?msgid=43025271)
- [appendValuesToArchiveSheet](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/27095918?msgid=27163801)